# Loading .Map file in Python Numpy or Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to plot a contour map. The data format is shown below. Currently I'm reading the data line by line and plotting the contour map, which consumes a lot of time.

Is it possible to load the data into Numpy or Pandas, so that I can process the data faster?

**Data description of single contour line:**

[image: Single Contour line (Polygon) description]

**After plotting, the contour map looks like:**

[image: Contour Map image]

**Sample Data:**

```
   290.0           7
339740.0    654429.0    339725.0    654442.0    339710.0    654502.0
339742.0    654522.0    339787.0    654524.0    339808.0    654477.0
339740.0    654429.0
   330.0          15
336127.0    652358.0    336275.0    652295.0    336472.0    652253.0
336533.0    652141.0    336575.0    652036.0    336716.0    651899.0
336726.0    651862.0    336699.0    651784.0    336519.0    651649.0
336422.0    651568.0    336372.0    651463.0    336279.0    651393.0
336167.0    651335.0    336227.0    651293.0    336385.0    651076.0
   310.0          21
338229.0    651803.0    338379.0    651945.0    338511.0    652046.0
338623.0    652069.0    338696.0    652044.0    338718.0    651994.0
338724.0    651914.0    338781.0    651942.0    338846.0    652037.0
338883.0    652100.0    338955.0    652182.0    339078.0    652230.0
339345.0    652411.0    339460.0    652539.0    339537.0    652549.0
339590.0    652549.0    339670.0    652539.0    339717.0    652487.0
339698.0    652379.0    339648.0    652294.0    339616.0    652024.0
   340.0          13
338384.0    651871.0    338486.0    651939.0    338538.0    651936.0
338586.0    651886.0    338596.0    651824.0    338664.0    651799.0
338779.0    651837.0    338949.0    652014.0    339220.0    652241.0
339475.0    652394.0    339533.0    652381.0    339575.0    652246.0
339571.0    652111.0
   360.0           5
339945.0    651435.0    339920.0    651465.0    339970.0    651482.0
339987.0    651455.0    339945.0    651435.0
```

**My Code:**

```
def ReadMapFile(mapfile):

    linesCountMapFile = sum(1 for line in open(mapfile))
    #open the map file
    file = open(mapfile, 'r')
    LoadCoord = False
    Ecount = 0
    #process the file line by line
    j = 0
    m={}
    n={}
    o={}
    X = []
    Y = []
    Z = []
    xx = []
    yy = []
    for mindex, line in enumerate(file):

        #ignore the first 4 line
        if mindex > 3:
            #Extract the Contour points
            if len(line) > 0 and LoadCoord == True:
                XY = line.split(" ")
                XY = [c for c in XY if c]
                for index, coord in enumerate(XY):
                    if index % 2 == 0:
                        xx.append(float(coord.strip()))
                    else:
                        yy.append(float(coord.strip()))
                if len(xx) == Ecount:
                    LoadCoord =False
                    X = xx
                    Y = yy
                    #Percentage of map loaded
                    print round((float(mindex)/float(linesCountMapFile))*100,2)
                    m[j]=X
                    n[j]=Y
                    o[j]=Z[0]

                    #Add XYZ to plot window
                    #addXYZ(X, Y, Z)

                    xx = []
                    yy = []
                    j = j+1

            #Extract the elevation of the map
            if len(line) == 24 and LoadCoord == False:
                Elevation = line.split(" ")
                Elevation = [z for z in Elevation if z]
                if len(Elevation[1]) < 6:
                    E = float(Elevation[0].strip())
                    Ecount = int(Elevation[1])
                    ZVal = [E]*(Ecount)
                    #Z.append(ZVal)
                    Z = ZVal #.append(ZVal)
                    #print Z  
                    LoadCoord = True

    file.close()

    ConX = m
    ConY = n
    ConZ = o
    #Return Dictionary of X, Y, Z
    return ConX, ConY, ConZ
d = ReadMapFile("Test.map")

print d
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you included a simple version of the code you've used to get what you already have

Comment: That way, people could do a run time comparison between the solution you already have and their's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you gave no baseline, here is some code to parse your file, that should be relatively fast when compared to naive solutions:

```
import struct
import pandas as pd

fieldwidths = (
    (8, 12),
    (8, 12, 12, 12),
    (8, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12),
)
fmtstrings = [
    ' '.join('{}{}'.format(abs(fw), 'x' if fw < 0 else 's')
             for fw in fieldwidth) for fieldwidth in fieldwidths]
fieldstructs = [struct.Struct(fmtstring) for fmtstring in fmtstrings]
parsers = [fieldstruct.unpack_from for fieldstruct in fieldstructs]

def get_contours(filename):
    contours = []
    points = []
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        points_left = 0
        for line in f:
            if points_left >= 3:
                x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3 = parsers[2](line)
                points.append((float(x1), float(y1)))
                points.append((float(x2), float(y2)))
                points.append((float(x3), float(y3)))
                points_left -= 3

            elif points_left == 2:
                x1, y1, x2, y2 = parsers[1](line)
                points.append((float(x1), float(y1)))
                points.append((float(x2), float(y2)))
                points_left = 0

            elif points_left == 1:
                x, y = parsers[0](line)
                points.append((float(x), float(y)))
                points_left = 0

            else:
                elevation, length = parsers[0](line)
                elevation = float(elevation)
                points_left = int(length)
                points = []

            if points_left == 0:
                contours.append(pd.Series(points, name=elevation))

        return contours
```

**Results:**

```
0    (339740.0, 654429.0)
1    (339725.0, 654442.0)
2    (339710.0, 654502.0)
3    (339742.0, 654522.0)
4    (339787.0, 654524.0)
5    (339808.0, 654477.0)
6    (339740.0, 654429.0)
Name: 290.0, dtype: object

0     (336127.0, 652358.0)
1     (336275.0, 652295.0)
2     (336472.0, 652253.0)
3     (336533.0, 652141.0)
4     (336575.0, 652036.0)
5     (336716.0, 651899.0)
6     (336726.0, 651862.0)
7     (336699.0, 651784.0)
8     (336519.0, 651649.0)
9     (336422.0, 651568.0)
10    (336372.0, 651463.0)
11    (336279.0, 651393.0)
12    (336167.0, 651335.0)
13    (336227.0, 651293.0)
14    (336385.0, 651076.0)
Name: 330.0, dtype: object

....
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working as I expected, and much faster than my code. Sorry for my bad English. Thank you for correction it.